# Scope en C# para extraer informacion de una computadora mediante la clase WMI

Tags: c#, scope

Al intentar conectarme a otra computadora me manda "Fallo de conexion".

NO se si sea error de credenciales, pero le mandé un `ping` a la computadora y si me responde igual con las conexiones remotas.

Este es mi código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Management;

namespace capaDatos
{
    public  class conexion
    {
        public ManagementScope ConectarWMI(string strBibliotecaWMI,bool blnHasDomain, 
            bool blnIsRemote, string strServer, string strUsername, 
            string strPassword, string strAuthority= null)

        {
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope();
            try
            {
                ConnectionOptions opciones = new ConnectionOptions();
                opciones.EnablePrivileges = true;
                opciones.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
                if (blnHasDomain == true)
                {
                    opciones.Authority = string.Format(@"ntlmdomain:{0}", strAuthority);

                }

                if (blnIsRemote)
                {
                    opciones.Username = strUsername;
                    opciones.Password = strPassword;
                }


                scope.Path.Path = string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\{1}", strServer, strBibliotecaWMI);

                Console.WriteLine(scope.Path.Path);
                scope.Options = opciones;
                scope.Connect();
                if (scope.IsConnected) { Console.WriteLine("Conexion exitosa"); }
                else { Console.WriteLine("Fallo de conexion"); }
            }
            catch(ManagementException me) { Console.WriteLine("ManagementException" + " ---> " + me.Message); }
            catch (Exception ex ) { Console.WriteLine("Exception" + " : " +       ex.Message); }
            return scope;
        }

    }
}

--------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using capaDatos;
using System.Management;

namespace capaNegocio
{
    public class AccesoWMI
    {
        public void Pruebas()
        {
            WMI c = new WMI();
            c.ToGet_Win32_NetworkAdapter();
        }

        public void pruebasRemotas()
        {
            conexion cone = new conexion();
            cone.ConectarWMI("cimv2", false, true, "JohnnyDroop", "Dogy", "pandora864", null);
        }
    }
}

-------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using capaNegocio;

namespace dgtsi_pruebas
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AccesoWMI w = new AccesoWMI();
            //w.Pruebas();

            w.pruebasRemotas();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste el Firewall?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-mx/library/aa822854(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Lo desactive completamente para las pruebas pero ni asi..